# The "unusual" feature of the Arguments object

Tags: javascript, arguments

This is a quote from the Core JavaScript Reference in "JavaScript, the Definitive Guide" regarding the `arguments` object:

> In non-strict mode, the Arguments object has one very unusual feature.
>   When a function has named arguments, the array elements of the
>   Arguments object are synonyms for the local variables that hold the
>   function arguments. The Arguments object and the argument names
>   provide two different ways of referring to the same variable. Changing
>   the value of an argument with an argument name changes the value that
>   is retrieved through the Arguments object, and changing the value of
>   an argument through the Arguments object changes the value that is
>   retrieved by the argument name.

In simple terms, what does this mean? An example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function x(a, b) {
  arguments[1] = "foo";
  console.log(b);
}

x("hello", "world");
```

You'll see `"foo"` in the console. The `arguments` object has array-like properties that *alias* the formal parameters declared by the function. That means that when you change `arguments[0]`, that also changes the value of the first explicitly-declared formal parameter. There's no other way in JavaScript to alias variables, so that makes `arguments` "unusual".

Comment: What's that got to do with being in strict mode or not? The console outputs `"foo"` in both cases.

Comment: @shmuli: with "use strict" it logs "world" in my copy of Chrome... same goes for  `b = "foo";  console.log( arguments[1]);`

Comment: @shmuli good question - I haven't seen anything about "strict" mode changing that aspect of the `arguments` object behavior. Understand that things are in flux, so perhaps that was a thing that was once contemplated but later changed. *edit* - How did you test the strict version?

Comment: @dandavis you're right; it works. I accidentally dropped a typo in there.